# WCF references in Metro app (Dev 11/Windows 8)

Tags: .net, wcf, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have the following configuration:

A Windows Phone application (A) that references a Portable Class Library (B), which in turn works with a WCF service (C).  These three all work together with no issues.  The application (A) has no reference to the WCF service - all references to the WCF service are contained in the PCL (B).

I am now attempting to create a Metro style app (D), which references the Portable Class Library (B) used in the prior (functional) application as a project reference.  There is no reference to the WCF service in application (D), since (as was the case with app A) this is all abstracted out inside of the Portable Class Library (B).

Unfortunately, I promptly get an error "Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'WCFService.IService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section' when I attempt to run app D.  The error appears inside of PCL (B) at the point that my ServiceClient is newed up.

I have been googling this for a while now with no luck, since most solutions are geared towards non-Metro apps (and my app works fine with WP7 and Studio 2010).  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted to build your PCL in VS 2012 for Windows 8?

I also developed a WCF service that I hoped I could utilize in both my Windows 8 app and Windows Phone 7 app. I dont have the extra obfuscation of wrapping it in a PCL but because I did not do that I was made painfully aware that the endpoint contracts had changed. So now, I have 2 sets of WebService auto-generated code which I include in each separate project file and on top of that I also have different calling conventions for the two platforms. On Windows Phone 7 I had to create callbacks that handle the finalization of the asynchronous web requests whereas on Windows 8 I can simply await the result of the call to the web request and it returns any result in an appropriate structure.

Could it be possible that your PCL is trying to deal with this in the background and failing miserably?